# Deserializing Generic Types from a ClassLouder class with GSON

Tags: java, json, generics, reflection, gson

I´m trying to parse a JSON file using GSON, the problem is that I´m using a Class that it was previously loaded by ClassLoader.

```
File root = new File("./build/classes");
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { root.toURI().toURL() });

Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName("events.Source", true,classLoader);


// JSON --> Java "Get the actual type"
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<loadedClass>>() {}.getType(); 

Gson gson = new Gson();

ArrayList<loadedClass> resourcesList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

That returns a **com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap** not a **List of my own loadedClass**.  Any help?

Comment: this code will not compile - loadedClass is not a type name and hence cannot be a type argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here a default implementation of ParametrizedType:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Generics/DefaultimplementationoflinkjavalangreflectParameterizedType.htm

properly prepared, such a type could be used to represent a generic type, which may work with GSON. Without having tested it, your code might then look like this:

```
File root = new File("./build/classes");
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {
   root.toURI().toURL()
});
Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName("events.Source", true,classLoader);

// JSON --> Java "Create the actual type"
Type listType = new DefaultParameterizedType(ArrayList.class, loadedClass);

Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<loadedClass> resourcesList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```